# c# windows service - how to schedule multiple task

Tags: c#, windows-services, scheduled-tasks, task-parallel-library

I have a `Windows Service` in `C#` that runs two schedule tasks using `timers`.

```
/// <summary>
        /// Intialize task Timers
        /// </summary>
        protected void InitializeService()
        {
            
            if (_model != null )
            {
              
               // initialize employee timer
                    if (affiliate_timer == null)
                    {
                        affiliate_timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                        affiliate_timer.AutoReset = true;
                        affiliate_timer.Interval = _model.Interval_Affiliate * 60000;
                        affiliate_timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(affiliate_timer_Elapsed);
                    }
                    // Enable affiliate Timer!!
                    affiliate_timer.Enabled = true;



                // initialize invoice timer
                    if (invoice_timer == null)
                    {
                        invoice_timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                        invoice_timer.AutoReset = true;
                        invoice_timer.Interval = _model.Interval_Invoice * 60000;
                        invoice_timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(invoice_timer_Elapsed);
                    }
                    // Enable invoice Timer!!
                    invoice_timer.Enabled = true;
             
            }  
            
        }
```

Each timer can have different intervals.

I have the need to add more jobs or tasks than can run based on a dynamic interval but I don't want to create 10 timers if I need 10 tasks. So maybe instead of timers using `System.Threading.Task` library could work.

> Any idea on the best way to implement this? Of course more than 1 task can run simultaneously.

Comment: Why don't you want to create one timer per task?

Comment: Can I do what im doing right now with just one timer?

Comment: I would consider setting up a scheduling list for each process/task you want to run, and only using the timer to check the schedule and then running each task when its scheduled time has come. For simple schedules you could do this yourself but if you need complex scheduling logic a library might help, I've briefly used Quartz.Net and had success... https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Comment: You could probably do it using a single timer, along with some complex calculation of intervals, but why bother? Do you have any suspicion that scheduling 10 (or 100 or 1000) timers may be inefficient or cause other issues?